# Kotlin with Dagger2&Databinding occur : Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'

Tags: android, data-binding, kotlin, dagger-2

I got a problem with Kotlin when using Databing  and Dagger2.Here is my gradle code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'              //Kotlin
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'   //KotlinExtension
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'                 //KotlinKapt


android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.androidCompileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.androidBuildToolsVersion
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sirius.cybird"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.androidMinSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.androidTargetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    //DataBinding
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    def appDependencies = rootProject.ext.appDependencies
    //项目依赖
    def testDependencies = rootProject.ext.appTestDependencies
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation appDependencies.kotlin
    implementation appDependencies.appcompact
    implementation appDependencies.appDesign
    implementation appDependencies.cardView
    implementation appDependencies.recycleView
    implementation appDependencies.palttte
    implementation appDependencies.percent
    implementation appDependencies.suportV4
    //Constraint
    implementation appDependencies.constrain
    //Rx+Retrofit
    implementation appDependencies.retrofit
    implementation appDependencies.retrofitConverter
    implementation appDependencies.retrofitAdapter
    implementation appDependencies.rxJava
    implementation appDependencies.rxAndroid
    implementation appDependencies.rxLifecycle
    implementation appDependencies.rxLifecycleComponent
    //BRVAH
    implementation appDependencies.brvah
    //RxPermission
    implementation appDependencies.rxPermission
    //SystemBar
    implementation appDependencies.systembar
    //Dagger
    implementation appDependencies.dagger
    kapt appDependencies.daggerCompiler
    //Glide
    implementation appDependencies.glide
    implementation appDependencies.glideOkHttp
    kapt appDependencies.glideComplier
    //DataBinding
    kapt appDependencies.databindingCompiler
    //Stetho
    implementation appDependencies.stetho
    //ObjectBox
    debugImplementation appTestDependencies.obBrowser
    releaseImplementation appDependencies.obBrowser
    //magicIndicator
    implementation appDependencies.magicIndicator
    //bottomNavgationBar
    implementation appDependencies.bottomNavBar
    //multiStateView
    implementation appDependencies.multiStateView
}
apply plugin: 'io.objectbox'                //ObjectBox
kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
```

And when I delete the code `kapt appDependencies.daggerCompiler`, the project is build success. And when i add this line in gradle, the gradle occur :
`api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.`, and the databing is all broken.
The environment of AndroidStudio and gradle version is `3.2.0-alpha09`.
The kotlin version is `1.2.21`.
I try to update kotlin-version to `1.2.31` or update Dagger2 version to `2.12` it's not working too.
What's the problem with the code?

Answer (score 0):

Will I found the question now.
That I define a dagger Module, But I lose the `@Module` annotation in the class file. And I have solve it now/.